# Facebook message notification showing blank message

Tags: macos, software-update

Since I updated the system to 10.11.5, the Facebook message notification is not showing message text.
[image]

Is this a bug in this software upgrade of OSX?

Comment: What have you tried to do to fix it? Have you disabled Facebook in System Preferences > Notifications, and then turned it back on?

Comment: I am having the same problem. Switching Facebook notifications to "None" and back to "Banners" had no effect.

Comment: It isn't an OS update problem because it happens on 10.9.5 as well. It must be an issue from Facebook's side.

Comment: Same for me. No fix found yet.

Comment: @IconDaemon - it sounds from your comment that yours are still working?

Comment: I don't use Notifications. Sometimes toggling the setting off, then back on, can reset messed up settings. I assume this didn't work for you?

Comment: This is probably a conscious decision on Facebook's part, since they want you to use Messenger. If you use https://www.messenger.com/, and turn on Desktop Notifications (and your browser supports it, at least Chrome and Firefox do), part of the message appears in the notification. Though, not as much of the message, since there's an extra line "via www.messenger.com" taking up some space now.

Comment: Interesting... This happened to me after the second to the last OS update I did (I don't remember what version I have).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This change is not a result of your specific OS X version. The change is on the server end by Facebook as they control what data to send to your Mac and the reason the text isn't showing is the text is no longer sent.

You might contact Facebook support to see if they are aware of this change - perhaps it's unintentional or you can so figure the web app to send the extra data to your browser.

Comment: This is probably to force people to use the dedicated Messenger website.

Comment: @pentavalentcarbon That would seem to align with Facebook investing money in a new message portal and also cracking down on web access to their site where people have ad blockers and Facebook blocks the blockers and then the blockers adapt, etc....